# How to get specific hyperlink object based on text using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

```
<a href="test1" onclick="calltest1()"> X1  </a>
<a href="test1" onclick="calltest2()"> X2 </a>
<a href="test1" onclick="calltest3()"> X3 </a>
```

I need to get the hyperlink object based on the text inside ex: x1 and bind a function to it. Can you please suggest the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery Contains selector https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

`$("a:contains('X1')")`